# Is it possible to mergeattribute (style, background)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some if-statements and I want to set the color of a textbox depending on the if-statement. I tried

```
mergeattribute("style","background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)")
```

...something like that.

Is it possible to do this way? Do I have the wrong syntax?

Comment: do You want do it in View or not?

Comment: Razor doesn't have that kind of syntax. Are you creating your own helper?

Comment: it is placed in a helpers-class

Comment: It is easy in Razor rather than with helper-class

Comment: It should work - what is happening when you use your helper?

Comment: i believe i have the wrong syntax cause it wont change the color of the textbox